# Anchors in a solid plaster wall

Tags: plaster, anchor

I was going to hang a heavy whiteboard on my plaster walls using molly bolts, but when I went to drill the holes, the drill bit never broke through - it penetrated (exactly) 2" into the wall before hitting something hard and stopping. So molly bolts and wing anchors are out. Is there anything that will work in this case?

I estimate that the whiteboard weighs about 60 pounds, and it has 6 mount points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know what stopped your drill? If it's brick then use a masonry bit and a hammer drill to make a hole. Then use masonry anchors in the brick.

Comment: It's hard to tell. It didn't give easily to my 5/16" wood drill bit, but I didn't want to apply much pressure until I knew what I was dealing with. I just see plaster dust in the hole. The outside walls of the building are brick, but this isn't an outside wall. There's no way to anchor to the plaster itself, huh?

Comment: Could be cinder-blocks or a brick load bearing wall, you can take a nail an tap it against it to get a feel for it.